# Print something on a certain space on the terminal in bash

Tags: bash, terminal

I made a script that tells me my battery life on my laptop every 10 minutes on the command line, but the problem is that it echoes it on the command line. I'd like for it to print it for example on the top-right corner of the terminal.

Is that possible?

Example:
This is the terminal window:

```
=====================
|texttexttexttexttex|
|t                  |
|moretext           |
|somethingsomething |
|me@me:~$...        |
=====================
```

And after the command, this is the result:

```
=====================
|texttexttextBAT-50%|
|t                  |
|moretext           |
|somethingsomething |
|me@me:~$...        |
=====================
```

So it overwrites whatever was written there.

Answer (score 10):

Use [terminal escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to move the cursor around. Virtually all terminals use a common set of escape sequences which are sufficient here, standardized by ANSI and made popular with the VT100. But you can use the [terminfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) database to look up escape sequences for your terminal, with the double benefit of portability and readability. You can use the [`tput`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tput.1.html) utility to emit [terminfo capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html).

```
print_in_top_right () {
  local columns=$(tput cols)           # get the terminal width
  local text=${1:0:$columns}           # truncate the text to fit on a line if needed
  tput sc                              # Save the Cursor position
  tput cup 0 $((columns - ${#text}))   # move the CUrsor Position to the top line, with just enough space for $text on the right
  printf %s "$text"
  tput rc                              # Restore the Cursor position saved by sc
}
```

Note that as soon as the terminal scrolls, this piece of text will scroll with it. There's no generic facility for keeping some text superimposed onto the terminal. If you want that, you need a terminal emulator with this feature, which usually reserves a dedicated line for this purpose. Most graphical terminal emulators let you see the window title which you can set with the [xterm-compatible escape sequence](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Operating-System-Commands:OSC-Ps;Pt-ST:Ps-=-l;c.1091) `OSC 2` (`OSC` is `ESC ]`).

```
set_window_title () {
  printf '\e]2;%s\007' "$1"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To write MSG at line 11, col 31 on the terminal, and put the shell prompt back at the bottom of the window:

```
echo "$( tput cup 10 30 )${MSG}$( tput cup ${LINES} 0))" && echo
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you assuming `BATTERY=50`

It finds the number of columns of your terminal and then adjust the cursor for your text and print "BAT $BATTERY%"

`echo "$(tput cup 0 $(expr $(tput cols) - 7))BAT $BATTERY%" && echo`